# I have problem running android emulator on M1 mac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator, apple-m1

I'm not able to get an Android app to launch in the Emulator on an M1 Mac.
I've very carefully followed instructions for setting up an arm-based emulator
but when I run it shows

```
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > com.google.common.base.VerifyException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Comment: Try with `--stacktrace` option as it suggests

Answer (score 1):

the android studio emulators for the m1 mac aren't compatible with arm based systems yet coz Apple M1 lacks of virtualization support

the problem also seems constant with the Rosetta build of android studio but to be fare I dont even know what the Rosetta build even is though if it is of help try this
[page](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/662807)

Comment: This does not look anything related to the Emulator, it's probably related to the gradle build task failing